# Calculating x-height in .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, fonts, font-size

How can we calculate x-height of a font (typeface) without needing .NET 3.0 or later (for example I would like to avoid `System.Windows.Media` namespace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question clearly states x-height, all the answers talk about height, which is not at all the same thing. `MeasureString` and `MeasureCharacterRanges` don't provide x-height.

Anyway, my answer would be: no, x-height is not available (in any way) in .Net 2.0.

Comment: Although this is marked as answer, it is wrong. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this: [Font.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.height(v=VS.80).aspx) or Perhaps this: [How to: Obtain Font Metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I am looking for specifically [x-height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height). `System.Windows.Media` includes the required value [Typeface.XHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.typeface.xheight%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Or are you looking for a way to calculate the height of a text rendered with a font? In that case you can use the [TextRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.aspx) class with the [MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx) function. This is available from .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you may use the [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace, you might want to use the [`Graphics.MeasureString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) method. Otherwise, do as Josh says, perhaps.

Your question might not be detailed enough for further assistance.

**EDIT #1**

The `Graphics.MeasureString()` method's return type is a [`System.Drawing.SizeF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizef_members(v=VS.80).aspx). This `SizeF` class provides three properties which among them you have these two:

1. [`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizef.height(v=VS.80).aspx);
2. [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizef.width(v=VS.80).aspx).

If this is not what you want, them I don't get your point. If it is so, I'm sorry.

I hope this helps anyway! =)

Comment: Or use the TextRenderer class. In that case you don't need an instance of a Graphics object.

Comment: @Patrick: Or using the TextRenderer class works as well. I always forget about this class. I personally don't really have to work with neither of these, but have worked with a .NET PDF library which works in graphical mode, so I kept this in mind with the `MeasureString` method. Thanks for the info! =)

Comment: I will have access to Graphics object. In the worst case I will have to calculate height of 'x' using either `MeasureString` or `MeasureCharacterRanges`.

Answer (score 0):

All answers here are wrong.
You CAN do that in .NET 2.0 but you need PInvoke.

You have to call the `GetGlyphOutline()` API and pass one character: A lowercase "x".
From `gmBlackBoxY` and `gmptGlyphOrigin.y` you can calculate the x-height. This will require a TrueType or Vector font to be selected into the Device Context (DC).

WARNING: Be aware that not all fonts have lower case characters and that some fonts don't even define an "x" character. In this case the x-height cannot be determined.